# Finding the average of an unknown amount of numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few different questions on this post related to the same thing.

(This code lets you insert fractions and it finds the average of them)

1.How would I be able to do this when the amount of numbers is unknown? To accomplish this for three numbers I would do `((eng1n + eng2n + eng3n) / (eng1d + eng2d + eng3d)) * 100` (variables ending in n are the numerator of the fraction while variables ending in d are the denominator), but how would I do this with an unknown amount of numbers?

2.I'll start off the webpage with 6 inputs (3 fractions, because I have one input for the numerator and one for the denominator) but how can I make a button that creates another set of inputs?

This would be easy normally, but how would I do this so that they each had their own unique id? The ids would follow a pattern (engNUMBERn, engNUMBERd, and each set's number is one higher than the last set) which might make this possible. However, it would also be a challenge to incorporate them into the equation above without knowing the amount of them.

3.My last question shouldn't be too hard, lets say we have two fractions so the equation is `((eng1n + eng2n) / (eng1d + eng2d)) * 100`. How can I make it so that if only the numerator or only the denominator of the fraction are filled then both the numerator and denominator are removed from the equation? Thanks!

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<div id='english' class='class'>English 1</div>
  <div id='engBookTests' class='type'>Book Tests</div>
  <div>
<div><input id='eng1n' type='number' placeholder='##' onkeyup='update()' onchange='update()' class='input'>/<input id='eng1d' type='number' placeholder='##' onkeyup='update()' onchange='update()' class='input'></div>
<div><input id='eng2n' type='number' placeholder='##' onkeyup='update()' onchange='update()' class='input'>/<input id='eng2d' type='number' placeholder='##' onkeyup='update()' onchange='update()' class='input'></div>
<div><input id='eng3n' type='number' placeholder='##' onkeyup='update()' onchange='update()' class='input'>/<input id='eng3d' type='number' placeholder='##' onkeyup='update()' onchange='update()' class='input'></div>
</div>

<script>
function update() {
  var eng1n = document.getElementById('eng1n').value;
  var eng1d = document.getElementById('eng1d').value;
  var eng2n = document.getElementById('eng2n').value;
  var eng2d = document.getElementById('eng2d').value;
  var eng3n = document.getElementById('eng3n').value;
  var eng3d = document.getElementById('eng3d').value;
  if (eng1n != "" && eng1d != "") {
    var engBTA = ((eng1n + eng2n + eng3n) / (eng1d + eng2d + eng3d)) * 100
    document.getElementById('engBookTests').innerHTML = "Book Tests (" + engBTA + "%)"
  }
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.class {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.type {
}

.input {
  left: 0;
  width: 14px;
  border: 0;
  direction: ltr;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks kind of like an assignment tbh

Comment: It's not, I'm just doing a ton of random projects to help me learn code and I decided to try to make something that lets you edit certain assignments in your gradebook and see how it affects your grade which isn't too easy because they're all weighted

Comment: you can't find an average of an unknown number of numbers considering that average is defined as the total of a set of numbers divided by the count of numbers in the set ... if that is unknown, then how can you even have the total, let alone the count? (I'm assuming *maths* isn't one of the subjects in the gradebook :p )

Comment: I'm too tired to write a proper answer. Instead here are two paths to investigate: select elements by common property (such as class) and do array operations on it. Or, write a loop trying to select the element with the next identifier until it returns no matching elements and then do the array operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code you seek.I remade your function and added one to add a new fraction.

This is what i changed:

1. I made a button that insert the fraction element so you can add as
   much as you want.
2. Removed `input` ids and gave classes fot there diferent values
3. Remade your `update()` function so it can work with as many inputs as you want.

   Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```js
function update() {
var nums =  document.getElementsByClassName('num');
var dens =  document.getElementsByClassName('den');

 var sumN = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i< nums.length; i++){
    sumN += +nums[i].value;
   }
    var sumD = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i< dens.length; i++){
    sumD += +dens[i].value;
   }
   
  var engBTA = ( sumN/sumD) * 100;
  document.getElementById('engBookTests').innerHTML = "Book Tests (" + engBTA + "%)";


}


function newFrac() {
var elem = "<input type='number' placeholder='##' onkeyup='update()' onchange='update()' class='input num'>/<input type='number' placeholder='##' onkeyup='update()' onchange='update()' class='input den'>"
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = elem;
  document.getElementById('fractions').appendChild(temp);
  
}
```

```css
.class {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.type {}

.input {
  left: 0;
  width: 14px;
  border: 0;
  direction: ltr;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<div id='english' class='class'>English 1</div>
<div id='engBookTests' class='type'>Book Tests</div>
<div id="fractions">

  <div>
    <input type='number' placeholder='##' onkeyup='update()' onchange='update()' class='input num'>/
    <input type='number' placeholder='##' onkeyup='update()' onchange='update()' class='input den'>
  </div>

</div>
<button onclick='newFrac()'>New</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! You are a genius! I was expecting this to take a super long time but you've helped a ton!

Comment: @Andrew happy to help.  Code on!

Comment: Just an FYI, I was using this and I realized that when you add the numbers they act as strings so if I averaged 10/20 and 20/10, the total numerator should be 30 and the total denominator should be 30, but they would be 1020 and 2010. I was able to fix this by adding a + to the beginning of `nums[i].value;` and `dens[i].value;`, just wanted to let ya know

Comment: @Andrew you are right. Edited to fit comment. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

1) An array with a for loop, or just [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

2) You'd have a parent div, and on the click of the button you'd create an element with `document.createElement` and then append it with `Element.appendChild`. You can make a subtract button that removes the most recent one, or you can put each set into a wrapper and add a button to remove the wrapper in each one, as seen [here](http://vvvland.ml/the-jungle/game.html), on the first screen. You can use `document.createElement` to make a new ID for each one but that seems like a hassle, so I'd suggest reading through the div. I did this in that game (that I linked) by using `Array.from(document.querySelector(".wrapper > input"))` (since I only had one input, it might be a little more complicated for you) and looping through that array to get the values.

**EDIT**: Looking at the comments, Slava Knyazev pointed out that you can simply add a class to each input, and while that was what I was kind-of hinting at, I didn't really make it clear. That would definitely be the easier way to go, even if it might be a bit harder to create a subtracting button

3) If `<input>.value` is empty-string (or 0, since you're using `type="number"`) then skip it in whatever function you use to read it

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Here's the function you seek:

```js
function average(){
  for(var i=0,sum=0,l=arguments.length; i<l; i++){
    sum += arguments[i];
  }
  return sum/l;
}
console.log(average(1, 3, 52, 77));
/* you could use on the dom like
var doc = document;
function Q(selector, withinElement){
  var w = withinElement || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
var numElements = Q('input[type=number]'), nums = [];
for(var i=0,l=numElements.length; i<l; i++){
  nums.push(numElements[i].value);
}
var avg = average.apply(null, nums);
console.log(avg);
*/
```

Comment: Why don't you use Array.reduce for summing? Like this: `array.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr)`. Also, it would be easier to just take an array as arguments, because it would be easier to call with several different numbers of unknown length

Comment: It makes the code more efficient and solves the fact that you have to do `average.apply(null, nums)`

It seems to me like this `average` function is more general-purpose than what Andrew can really use easily

Comment: Now I'm just laughing. Functions are supposed to be general purpose. My average function takes any amount of arguments and gives you the average. `.apply()` was used to pass an Array as a bunch of arguments.

Comment: I understand what array does. I know that in many cases, functions can and should be general purpose. However, passing an array as the arguments, in this case, makes it more readable, easier to use in Andrew's case, and not that much harder to use generally (just put `[]` around your arguments). The only reason I'd use your solution is if I was making an extremely user-friendly library, which we aren't doing. Even then - input as an array solves the whole arbitrary length problem more easily than `[].split.call` *and* would be easier for people who were using the function with arbitrary length

Comment: I meant `I understand what apply does` but I cannot edit my comment on mobile for some reason

Comment: You can only update comments for 5 minutes from when you post them. Of course, you can copy your comment, delete it, then paste it in a new comment and edit it, before posting.

Comment: Thank you. I don't usually comment and answer, or ask on stackoverflow that much :)

Comment: Leaving the architectural decisions aside, why use `[].slice.call(arguments)`? `arguments` is sufficiently Array-like to be used in your loop directly. And [`[].slice.call(arguments)` kills optimization in V8](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#32-leaking-arguments).

Comment: `@AuxTaco`. It's not needed in that function, true. I do that in most of my functions that take the `arguments` Array Like Object, because it's not an Array, therefore does not actually support Array functions. It makes it easy to add things to the function without thinking if I can use `.pop()` and things of that nature. I'll change that part of the example if it makes you happy, though, since I'm not using any Array methods.